# change Sequel Column String Size

Tags: ruby, sequel

I'd like to change a String colums' size with a migration.

I tried

```
Sequel.migration do
  up do
    alter_table(:users) do
      set_column_type :car_model, :string, size: 30
    end
  end

  down do
  end
end
```

but that gives me a SQL syntax error migrating:

```
Sequel::DatabaseError: Mysql2::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'String(30) NULL' at line 1
```

Any way to do this?
So currently the field is a String of size 20, I'd like to make it a String of size 30.

Thanks in advance!

UPDATE
I also tried

```
set_column_type :car_model, char(30)
```

that however results in me getting a `String :car_model, :size=>255` column :/

Comment: Do you need to save any data?

Comment: that would be best :)

Comment: you can always write raw sql to modify that column

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were almost correct. You need to use `String` instead of `:string`:

```
set_column_type :car_model, String, size: 30
```

Note that that uses `varchar(30)`, not `char(30)`.  In general, unless you know you want `char`, you are better off with `varchar`.

Alternatively, anytime you want to force a database-specific type, you can just specify it as a string:

```
set_column_type :car_model, 'char(30)'
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know Sequel, but in Postgres you can use `change_column` with `:limit` like this:

`change_column :users, :car_model, :string, limit: 30`

Hope it helps!

Comment: hmm, that also results in a size of 255, weird :S

Comment: Can you show the whole migration file, when you try with this?

Comment: And maybe your schema.rb? Would be nice to see your database structure.